# Discord.py Buttons and drop down menu's, not getting the correct libraries

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

FIX: Add DiscordComponents(bot)

I'm trying to get either buttons or a drop-down menu allowing the user to make a selection. However, I have been unable to get it to work as either method still ends up giving me a components issue.

The error message being:
line 134, in rps
m = await ctx.send(
TypeError: send() got an unexpected keyword argument 'components'

I have pip installed discord_components and imported it. I'm confused about where the error message is coming from.

```
@bot.command(name = "rps")
async def rps(ctx):
    ch1 = ["Rock","Scissors","Paper"]
    comp = random.choice(ch1)

    yet = discord.Embed(title = f"{ctx.author.display_name}'s RPS game", description = "You have yet to select anything")

    win = discord.Embed(title = f"{ctx.author.display_name} Won!", descrption = "Congrats! You won.")

    out = discord.Embed(title = f"{ctx.author.display_name} was too slow.", descrption = "Okay then you were just too slow for me. ")

    lost = discord.Embed(title = f"{ctx.author.display_name} lost", descrption = "Aw darn. Unfortunatly you lost this one.")

    tie = discord.Embed(title = f"{ctx.author.display_name} tied with the bot!", descrption = "Well thats interesting. It was a tie.")


    m = await ctx.send(
        embed=yet,
        components=[Select(placeholder="Select 1", options=[SelectOption(label="Rock", value="Rock"), SelectOption(label="Paper", value="Paper"), SelectOption(label="Scissors", value="Scissors")])]
        ,
    )

    interaction = await bot.wait_for("select_option", check = lambda i: i.component[0].value == "A")
    await interaction.respond(content = f"{interaction.component[0].label} selected!")
```

What I imported and how my bot is defined:

```
import os, csv, random, discord, asyncio, pandas, requests, json, traceback
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord_components import DiscordComponents, Button, Select, SelectOption

load_dotenv()
botToken = os.getenv("DiscBotToken")
```

Comment: can you also send code for where you define bot and how and your imports

Comment: Updated, hopefully I gave you the correct information :)

Comment: Did you do `DiscordComponents(bot)` anywhere in your code?

Comment: Oh boy, that instantly fixed my issue. Why was the answer that easy and I didn't figure that out. I seriously appreciate that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't help you, but I can give you a working code.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_components import DiscordComponents, Select, SelectOption, Button,ButtonStyle
from discord.utils import get

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
DiscordComponents(bot)
print('Connected')

@bot.command()
async def button(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title='Test',description='Test text')

await ctx.send(embed=embed, components=[Button(label='Test', custom_id="test-id", style=ButtonStyle.red)])
interaction = await bot.wait_for(
"button_click", check=lambda inter: inter.custom_id == "test-id")

@bot.event
async def on_button_click(interaction):
    await interaction.respond(type=6)
        await interaction.author.send("Click")
```

And SelectMenu

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_components import DiscordComponents, Select, SelectOption, Button, ButtonStyle
from discord.utils import get

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    DiscordComponents(bot)
    print('Connected')

@bot.command()
async def sm(ctx):
    if ctx.author.id == 670325098598629377 or 426376741028888576:
        await ctx.send(
    '>>> 'Text',
    components = [
    Select(
        placeholder = 'SelectMenu',
        options = [
            SelectOption(label="SelectMenu1", value="value1"),
            SelectOption(label="SelectMenu2", value="value2"),
            SelectOption(label="SelectMenu3", value="value3"),
            SelectOption(label = "SelectMenu4", value = "value4"),
            SelectOption(label="SelectMenu5", value="value5"),
            SelectOption(label="SelectMenu6", value="value6"),
            SelectOption(label = "SelectMenu7", value = "value7"),
            SelectOption(label = "SelectMenu8", value = "value8")
            ])])

@bot.event
async def on_select_option(interaction):
    if interaction.message.id == 891587821368905728: #Message id(not obligatory)
        await interaction.respond(type=6)
        if interaction.values[0] == "value1":
            await interaction.author.send("Menu 1")
        elif interaction.values[0] == "value2":
            await interaction.author.send("Menu 2")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you use discord.py instead of other libraries/dependencies like `discord_components` or `nextcord`, etc.

- If you'd like to check views for discord.py v2, then go here
  → https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/tree/45d498c1b76deaf3b394d17ccf56112fa691d160/examples/views
- If you have a question or problem regarding your code, go to the discord.py discord server
  → https://discord.gg/dpy and say `?tester` in the `#testing` channel to get access to the v2 issues channel.

Comment: Note that the comment `"discord.py is archived, and was never OFFICIAL"` specifically referred to the version of the answer before [@Harper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18683114/harper)'s [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/31856307).